# HttpRequest's parameters default encoding in Java (Tomcat)

Tags: java, tomcat, encoding, httprequest

My Tomcat web server is using Struts framework (v1).

When reading request parameters, i need to recode the parameter from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 in order to get proper value.
e.g.

```
String fName = request.getParameter("fName");
String displayName = new String(fName.getBytes("ISO-859-1"), "UTF-8");
persistName(displayName);
```

**The question is why the default encoding is ISO-8859-1?**
Where is it defined and how to change it?

*Env details:*

- Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.62
- OS Name:        Linux
- JVM Version:    1.8.0_92-b14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, if I recall correctly, you can set the URIEncoding property on the connector to default to UTF-8.

According to [this link](https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-8.html#URIEncoding), the default under Tomcat 8 (when strict servlet compliance is off) is UTF-8.  Under Tomcat 7, at my company we set this explicitly.

In server.xml for the connector element(s):

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

According to the configuration documentation for the [Tomcat 7 HTTP connector](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html), this is by default ISO-8859-1.

The configuration documentation for the [Tomcat 8 HTTP connector](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html) does explicitly state that if org.apache.catalina. STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE is false, UTF-8 will be used.

I do have some inklings that this dates back to Servlet 2.4 specification which states that if no character encoding is specified, ISO-8859-1 is used.

Answer (score 0):

Check that encoding of your files are utf-8 and the charset meta tag in html are also set to utf-8.